# Getting the last inserted document Id

Tags: mongodb

I have tried to get the last saved documentId from the mongo database. But whatever I try I don't get anything back.
Can someone please hint me how to solve this in C# i have tried doing the sorts and take the last document but i don't get anything back.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not have such an operation.

If you want to know the id of inserted document, generate the id on the client side before inserting.